# AWS Polly Javascript SDK polly error ConfigError: Missing region in config at Request.VALIDATE_REGION

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, amazon-polly

I have a browser app that uses Polly and Lex Javascript SDK. I get this error
error ConfigError: Missing region in config at Request.VALIDATE_REGION
using this code

```
const awsPollyCredentials = {
    accessKeyId: pollyKey,
    secretAccessKey: pollySecret,
    region: "us-east-1",
  };
new AWS.Polly(awsPollyCredentials)
```

which is correct according the SDK docs.
It is not finding the region. Why not?

NOTE: I cannot use an AWS global config because my Lex calls use different credentials in same page. So I need a solution that gets passed into AWS.Polly()

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to get it to work with global credentials, even though the SDK docs says the Polly(options) accepts region.  It only works in global AWS.config

```
const awsPollyCredentials = {
accessKeyId: pollyKey,
secretAccessKey: pollySecret,
region: "us-east-1",
};
AWS.config.credentials = awsPollyCredentials;
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
```